# Open Python CEF application in secondary monitor

Tags: python, fullscreen, chromium-embedded

I am developing a POS application for which I need to develop a Python CEF application that will always open in secondary monitor (This CEF app will launch a page to show live updates to customer). I am new to CEF and python. I could find how to create simple CEF app but cant open that application in secondary monitor.

Is it possible for a CEF application to open itself in secondary monitor? Or I need the external script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for window management is currently limited in cefpython. You can set window parameters x,y,width,height by providing rect to WindowInfo.SetAsChild. Last time I checked this only worked on Linux and Mac. You can use a third party GUI framework such as wxPython and have more control over window management. Try google "wxpython create window on secondary monitor":

https://www.google.com/search?q=wxpython+create+window+on+secondary+monitor

Comment: Although I wasn't able to detect and open window on secondary monitor, i was able to push window by providing x/y position